# Vanilla JS assertion lib alternative to Meteor's check package

Tags: javascript, meteor, assertions

The application framework Meteor has a package called `check` that can be used to [assert boundaries on your inputs](http://docs.meteor.com/#matchpatterns), and related stuff. This is really kind of nifty, and very useful to have easy ways of checking that a string conforms to say ISO8601 or that an object contains certain fields.

Unfortunately this is a Meteor specific package, and I would like to have something similar for standalone use in vanilla js. Any alternatives worth mentioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is great vanilla js schema validation library called [js-schema](https://github.com/molnarg/js-schema). It allows to write schema in very clean way. It is great when you need to write big schemas and also precisely see from what path errors come from.

```
 var Duck = schema({              // A duck
  swim : Function,               //  - can swim
  quack : Function,              //  - can quack
  age : Number.min(0).max(5),    //  - is 0 to 5 years old
  color : ['yellow', 'brown']    //  - has either yellow or brown color
});

var result = Duck.errors({
  swim: function() {},
  quack: function() {},
  age: 6,
  color: 'green'
});

console.dir(result) 

{
   age: 'number = 6 is bigger than required maximum = 5',
   color: 'string = green is not reference to string = yellow AND
           string = green is not reference to string = brown'
}
// #########################
// source : js-schema README
```

**[js-schema is also packaged for meteor](https://atmospherejs.com/parhelium/js-schema)**

Disclaimer : I contributed to this library by writing `Schema.errors()` feature and created package for it.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can use only the selected Meteor package in your project, you don't have to load the whole platform?

In case of `check` this is pretty simple as it doesn't have many dependencies, so you can just use the package code as a library. See [its package.json file](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/check/package.js):

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.use(['underscore', 'ejson'], ['client', 'server']);
  api.export(['check', 'Match']);
  api.add_files('match.js', ['client', 'server']);
});
```

The only dependencies are `underscore` and `ejson`, and there is only one file. So as long as you have underscore and take care of EJSON, you can just add [this file](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/check/match.js) to your project and have `check` in vanilla JS. The `ejson` package can be dealt with similarly, or you can just precede the file with `EJSON = JSON;` and limit your checks to vanilla JSON objects.

Comment: Nice to know, but accepted the other answer, as that does not have any external deps. Although I am not too keen on the prototype extensions they use ...